# How to create a histogram in Python one data point at a time?

Tags: python

I need to create a histogram of a very large data set in python 3.  However, I cannot use a list to create a histogram because the list would be too large given my data.  I need a way to update a histogram as each data point is created.  That way my computer is only ever dealing with a single point and updating the plot.

I've been using matplotlib.  Tried plt.draw() but couldn't get it to work. (See code below)

```
#Proof of concept code

l = [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2]
n = 0
p = False
for x in range(0,6):
  n = l[x]
  if p == False:
    fig = plt.hist(n)
    p = True
  else:
    plt.draw()
```

I need a plot that looks like plt.hist(l).  But have only been getting the first point plotted.

Comment: What does this mean: " However, I cannot use a list to create a histogram because the list would be too large given my data"? How do you plan on holding the histogram in memory?

Comment: What does this mean: "Tried plt.draw() but couldn't get it to work."? How did it not work?

Comment: Where is the data? How is it created/retrieved?

Comment: My data is a list of numbers that is potentially millions longs.  I can hold the initial list but cannot create a new one to use to create a histogram.

Comment: My data is a list of numbers that I am doing arithmetic with and graphing a histogram of the results.

Comment: I read that the matplotlib function .draw() is supposed to update the last figure.  So I tried to use it to update my histogram as I added numbers.  This is what my example code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with Numpy? Numpy handles large arrays pretty well.

Here's an example using a random integer set from 1 to 3 (inclusive).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

arr_random = np.random.randint(1,4,10000)
plt.hist(arr_random)
plt.show()
```

It's very efficient to compute plt.hist() with Numpy arrays.

Comment: I am familiar with the name numpy but not overly with how to use it.  In regards to your suggestion, from my point of view, creating a list vs an array would present the same problem, because if I have a large enough data set, the array that is created from it would crash my code.  That is why I am trying to update the histogram as the code progresses, so my computer does not have to remember every output, only the current one it is adding to the histogram.

Comment: Where is the data coming from? Are you retrieving from a file?

Comment: The reason I ask, is because if it's from a binary file, for instance, you could iterate the file using count argument in numpy.fromfile(file, dtype=float, count=-1). Compute histo for each iteration, append to previous, repeat until you reach end of file, then plot the final result. In my opinion, better approach than placing all the data in memory if it's as large as you say...